# Get product video

Tags: magento2, product-images, video

I have added some videos to my product via the add video section under product "Images And Videos". I want to be able to display the videos added this way in a custom section. The code currently looks like this:

```
$images = $full_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach($images as $image){
  if(in_array($image->getFile(), $used_images)){
    continue;
  }
  ?>
  <li>
    <?php
    if($image->getMediaType() == "external-video") { 
      ?>
      <iframe width="640" height="480" src="<?php echo $image->getVideoUrl(); ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <?php
    } else { // general show an image
    ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $image->getUrl(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to display only certain images and videos in the list (hence the $used_images bit), so far it is working fine except the getVideoUrl for youtube returns me a wrongly formatted youtube url.

I get:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcdefghij

but I need:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/abcdefghij

It's possible for me to write some php code that would pull out the video code and get me the correct url but I want to know if their are magento methods for this or displaying videos/iframes. Creating my own methods shortcut here might cause me problems with other magento features (such as vimeo videos) not working in this display.

Answer (score 1):

Write code like that call

```
preg_replace("/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i","<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", $image->getVideoUrl());
```

Comment: This is functional and working but I was looking for a way to do this through magento framework/functions rather than preg_replace.

Comment: Okey i will check and provide the code

Comment: http://webdeveloperswall.com/php/generate-youtube-embed-code-from-url it is more clear i think :)

Comment: otherwise we will use preg_replace_callback method.

Answer (score -1):

You can get embeded code using,

```
$image->getVideo()
```

Now your iframe look like below way,

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $image->getVideo() ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Gave that a try but I'm getting null when calling that.

Comment: check which value is returned $full_product->getVideo()

Comment: Both return null. This is an image added via the image/media manager for magento 2 not a video attribute added to the product.

Comment: What is $image in your case? It's simple DataObject. It doesn't have any methods, and __call getVideo() will return nothing.